# Grid - HTML | CSS

Tags: html, css, sass, grid

[image]

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="item half-width">1</div>
 <div class="item half-width">2</div>
 <div class="item half-width">4</div>
 <div class="item half-width">5</div>
 <div class="item half-width">6</div>
 <div class="item full-width">7</div>
</div>
```

How do I write css for the html content so that I can get the above output as show in the picture which is scrollable in x direction. After once DOM is rendered completely , may be at some point of time , I need to remove the element  4 , so that 5 come in front and auto align.

Answer (score 2):

After reading more carefully your question i made a solution with `css grid` . I'm not an expert in css grid but i hope this solves your problem

```css
 .item:nth-child(4n),
.item:nth-child(4n-1) {
  order: 1;
  grid-row-start: 2
} 



.container {
  display: grid;
  max-width:100vw;
  overflow-x:scroll;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
  grid-template-rows: 150px 150px;
}

.item {
  height: 140px;
  margin: 5px;
  background:blue;
  color:white;
 
}
.item:last-child {
  grid-column-end:5;
  grid-column-start:3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item half-width">1</div>
  <div class="item half-width">2</div>
  <div class="item half-width">3</div>
  <div class="item half-width">4</div>
  <div class="item half-width">5</div>
  <div class="item half-width">6</div>
  <div class="item full-width">7</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184478/discussion-between-sri-vivek-and-mihai-t).

Answer (score -1):

Also, you can consider the CSS Grid, as you are trying to work with multidimensional structure.

---

```css
.container {
    padding: 20px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: 50px 90px;
    grid-gap: 5px;
}

.container .item {
    background: red;
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: #fff;
}

.container .two-column-right {
    grid-column: 3 / -1;
}

.container .two-column-left {
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='item'>1</div>
  <div class='item'>2</div>
  <div class='item'>3</div>
  <div class='item'>4</div>
  <div class='item two-column-left'>5</div>
  <div class='item two-column-right'>6</div>
</div>

<div class='container'>
  <div class='item'>1</div>
  <div class='item'>2</div>
  <div class='item'>3</div>
  <div class='item'>4</div>
  <div class='item'>5</div>
  <div class='item'>6</div>
  <div class='item two-column-right'>7</div>
</div>
```